# error CS0117 Resource.Layout does not contain a definition for tabbar and toolbar xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I have added another login source code project using add existing project to my project and i got this errors after clean solution and rebuilding
[image]

I renamed tabbar to tabbar2 and toolbar and tabbar from existing to toolbar1 and tabbar1

Comment: Try to delete bin and obj folder , restart visual studio , then rebuild  .

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem in my case I had to rename from:

```
layout/toolbar.xml
```

To

```
layout/Toolbar.xml
```

I was migrating from

android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

to

androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar:

From:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
```

To

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
```

This caused the following error when compiling:

```
Error   CS0117  'Resource.Layout' does not contain a definition for 'Toolbar'
```

Renaming from toobar.xml to Toolbar.xml fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also have faced with that problem. I have tried everything I find in the internet. For several days I was not able to find the solution, so I decided to wait for VS update.

Update is release, my VS is updated - nothing changes.

That is curious, but when I have changed the verbosity level of Xamarin Diagnostics and MSBuild output - I finally have gotten the build without errors.

So, the instruction which has solved my problem in VS 2019:

1. Go to **Tools** -> **Options** -> **Xamarin** -> **Android Settings**.
2. Set **Xamarin Diagnostics output verbosity** to **Detailed**.
3. Go to **Tools** -> **Options** -> **Projects and Solutions** -> **Build And Run**.
4. Set **MSBuid project build output verbosity** to **Detailed**.